# Disable accessing items from a particular list through REST

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-list

I have a List in Sharepoint 2016 Site Collection called Feedback. I want anonymous users be able to Add items to the list.

But I do not want anyone to read the query that list using a REST api like below

http://siteurl/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Feedback')

NOTE: My site collection is a public facing site (Publishing Portal)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turn off ability to use REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/100102/turn-off-ability-to-use-rest-api)

Comment: @Coder  it does not answer my question. I want to turn of rest api for only one list in the site collection. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Then for the specific url you need to deny access in the IIS.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint does not support this functionality. You could potentially use a Web Application Firewall in front of SharePoint to deny access to the absolute path. You may also be able to form a rule in Request Filtering on the IIS Web Site to deny access to the specific URI.